# cant start splash activity before Sherlockfragment Activity

Tags: android

Hi have sherlock fragment activity running which also contain slide menu and i want to have splash screen before this activity and i dont know how to make buttons work in this fragment activity

```
    package com.androidbegin.sidemenututorial;

    import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;

    public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

// Declare Variable
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
ListView mDrawerList;
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
MenuListAdapter mMenuAdapter;
String[] title;
String[] subtitle;
int[] icon;
Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment1();
Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment2();
Fragment fragment3 = new Fragment3();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);









    // Generate title
    title = new String[] { "Main Menu", "Setting",
            "About" };

    // Generate subtitle
    subtitle = new String[] { "", "",
            "" };

    // Generate icon
    icon = new int[] { R.drawable.action_about, R.drawable.action_settings,
            R.drawable.collections_cloud };

    // Locate DrawerLayout in drawer_main.xml
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    // Locate ListView in drawer_main.xml
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
    // opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);

    // Pass results to MenuListAdapter Class
    mMenuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(this, title, subtitle, icon);

    // Set the MenuListAdapter to the ListView
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);

    // Capture button clicks on side menu
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // Enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    // Locate Position
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment1);
        break;
    case 1:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment2);
        break;
    case 2:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment3);
        break;

    }
    ft.commit();
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    // Close drawer
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
    }
```

Comment: You should have your splashscreen in a separate Activity that is finished when this one starts http://blog.blundell-apps.com/tut-splashscreen-with-progress-bar/

Comment: yeah i had that in Splash.java and i ran a thread for 5 seconds and started this activity via intent but this gives an exception but in other activities i do the same thing and get no exception

Answer (score 0):

And you have added the Activity to the manifest?

Comment: yes i have ........as i have told earlier its working with other activities and apps that doesn't use fragments but this sherlock fragment activity doesn't run that gives an exception